# Subs sympy free vars with a string

Tags: python, sympy

I am parsing a custom format like "{a} + {b}" into a sympy expression. I have that working successfully. Now, is there a way to convert that sympy expression back to the original string, assuming I have a dictionary mapping the free variable names and the corresponding string-in-braces representation?

Assuming the free variables from the above are "a" and "b", I want to do something like

```py
str(expr.subs({'a': '{a}', 'b': '{b}'}))
```

but sympy doesn't seem to allow substituting in arbitrary strings like that.

Comment: @JohanC That worked! Post as an answer please so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass a [codegenerator](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html) (e.g. `StrPrinter`), and overwrite the function that outputs the free variables. You can copy the original function from the [sympy source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/utilities/codegen.py) and make some modifications.

Here is an example:

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.printing import StrPrinter

class CustomStrPrinter(StrPrinter):
    def _print_Symbol(self, expr):
        return f'{{{expr.name}}}'

a, b = sp.symbols('a b')
expr = a + b

custom_strPrinter = CustomStrPrinter().doprint
print(custom_strPrinter(expr))  # {a} + {b}
```

Comment: I inherited `sympy.printing.StrPrinter` instead of the C99 one, but otherwise this worked great.

Comment: Indeed, `StrPrinter` might be a better fit.  I used `C99CodePrinter` as I needed to customize it for a project. I updated the code with the simpler `StrPrinter`.